# Show and hide Statusbar in Windows Phone 8.1 just work first time

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-phone-8.1, statusbar

I´m using statusbar when loading things from internet into the app. I have two functions in App.xaml.cs which I use to hide and show but when I have called HideProgressAsync() once, next time I call ShowProgressAsync the status bar is not showed. What am I doing wrong? Missing a flag?

```
    public async Task ShowProgressAsync(string message)
    {
        var statusBar = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView();              
        statusBar.ProgressIndicator.Text = message;
        await statusBar.ProgressIndicator.ShowAsync();
    }

    public async Task HideProgressAsync()
    {
        var statusBar = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView();
        await statusBar.HideAsync();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code issue, in code above I hide the whole statusBar. Below is correct code

```
public async Task HideProgressAsync()
{
    var statusBar = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView();
    await statusBar.ProgressIndicator.HideAsync();
}
```